# Is there a specific name for the blackboard when it's white?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, image-identification

In now-days there are two types of *blackboards*: one is **green** (it's used with chalk) and the second is **white** (it's used with marker pen).

My question is if there is a specific name for white-blackboard? (In my language we simply refer to the white one as "white blackboard".)

[image: Whiteboard for pens]
[image: Green board for chalk]

Comment: It's a [whiteboard](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whiteboard) strangely enough :)

Comment: Thank you:) so if I saw people who referred to it as a blackboard, then they were wrong?

Comment: It depends - if it was a classroom, calling it a blackboard would be like calling a tissue a "[kleenex](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kleenex "a brand name")" . Teachers write on the blackboard, even if sometimes it is a whiteboard or it is green. If you were in an office, it wouldn't be natural to call it a blackboard. In an office, whiteboards are usual, so you might even call a pane of glass that someone uses like a whiteboard a whiteboard. Are you confused yet? I think you should add the part about people calling it a blackboard into your question.

Comment: I got it. you actually says that the word "blackboard" became to generic name in case of schools and collages and not in case of offices. Isn't it?

Comment: In my mind, calling a whiteboard a blackboard would be, well, a little weird.  But calling a blackboard a whiteboard is even weirder.  I'm not a student and don't spend much time in classrooms, but I'm not sure a school setting would change how I see it.

Comment: In the UK, it would be unusual for a whiteboard to be referred to as a blackboard, although the truncation to "board" would be commonplace.

Comment: And of course you can call all of them, whether white, green, or black,  "the board".   *Who would like to write the equation on the board?*

Answer (score 5):

The white coloured "blackboard" is actually called whiteboard commonly in corporates offices and such places, where people write on it with a marker pen.

The name is now well established, and has propagated into software as well, where some conference calling applications also provide a "virtual whiteboard" which the participants can annotate for others to see.

Comment: In today's drive for being politically correct (black versus white), also due to the fact that they can be green as indicated in the question, a *blackboard* is generally termed a *chalkboard* and a whiteboard is termed a *marker board*

Comment: Calling black black and white white is considered politically incorrect? :o  It sounds like a lot of people are evolving backwards these days.

Comment: I agree. Black is black and white is white. How someone got this to involve race I don't know.  I have heard the same with white and black coffee.  (Coffee with milk or coffee with no milk).